# What is the functionality of this React style expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
<Text
    style={[
        styles.buttonLabel,
        selectedValue === value && styles.selectedLabel,
    ]}
>{value}</Text>
```

Above is a piece of code extracted from the second example from the official docs of [react-native flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox). Can anyone explain the functionality of the expression in the `style` prop?

Comment: Please describe your problem in post. Do not do it in topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do not put the heart of the question in the title

Comment: Tutorial: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html which leads to these docs https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style and with that basic knowledge, you just need to figure out how the truthy checks work inside the array

Comment: Sure, will try to better draft this question.
This being my first question, was unaware of the norms.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `style` expects either a style (e.g an object with `width`, `background-color`, etc) or an array of styles. The expression `selectedValue === value && styles.selectedLabel` can result in two different values:

- `false` when `selectedValue !== value`. After all, `false && value` is `false`.
- `styles.selectedLabel` if `selectedValue === value`.

This results in `styles` being either `[styles.buttonLabel, false]` or `[styles.buttonLabel, styles.selectedLabel]`. The `false` will get ignored when combining the styles.

Basically, this is "add this extra style if this condition matches" in a single expression.

Comment: so basically it is (selectedValue === value) && styles.selectedLabel and styles.selectedLabel is effective if the first expression{in the parenthesis} evaluates to true. 

Thank you Kelvin!!

Comment: @Snehalsingh Yes indeed. When `a` in `a && b` is falsy (`undefined`, `null`, `false`, `""` or `0`), it'll immediately return `a` without even evaluating `b`. This is quite basic JavaScript, you can find plenty of tutorials on conditionals. Also when asking a question here, don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as the solution.